# Fixing Komodo Edit auto-indention for other editors

Tags: sublimetext2, coda, auto-indent, komodoedit

I've created a PHP project with Komodo Edit now i should migrating to another editor (Coda) but Komodo auto-indention is only valid and fine in Komodo! Coda and Sublime Text don't recognize indentions...

Is there any solution for fixing that?

Answer (score 0):

In order for a Text Editor to recognize the indentation levels some configuration is needed. All editors allow to select between tabs and spaces for the indentation. If you select spaces, you also select the number of them (usually 4 or 8). Try to find out how these things are set in your new editor and make sure you use the same settings across all editors.

Comment: I know about indention configuration but some editors have auto-indention to add tabs in code blocks. e.g. pressing Enter after a IF line, editor recognizes that to add an extra tab. This extra tab is not recognizable in other editor...